# after fwrite destination file is empty c language

Tags: c, fwrite

i am trying to open two files, put their content in an array and write array back to the file. However, after i use fwrite function the destination file is empty. Could anybody explain how to achive my goal?

data.txt file content:

```
1
2
3
```

i.txt file content:

```
3
4
5
```

here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fmain, *fnew, *fp;
    int i = 0,f = 0, length = 150, arr[length], chararr[length], sizearr;
    char line[130];
    int error;
    fmain = fopen("data.txt", "rw+");
    fnew = fopen("i.txt", "rw");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fnew) != NULL){
        arr[f] = atoi(line);
        f++;
    }
    fclose(fnew);
    // read data into array from data file

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fmain) != NULL){
        arr[f] = atoi(line);
        f++;
    }

    fclose(fmain);

    fp = fopen("data2.txt", "w");

    fwrite(arr, sizeof(char), sizeof(arr), fp);


    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

when i manually open data2.txt after i run the program it is empty but i would like to see something like:

```
1
2
3
3
4
5
```

Comment: You're writing it to `data2.txt` and it is a **binary file** of 300 or 600 bytes. What makes you to think it is empty? Why are you writing a binary file with extension `.txt`? Why are you using the `"w"` (text mode) to create a binary file?

Comment: I just want to write an array to a text file and that was the best i could come up with. Could you elaborate on how i can do it since my solution is wrong?

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question and provide input with `data.txt` having `1`, `i.txt` having `2` and the resulting file having *what* in it? I.e. the [mcve]. You never state the expected output. It *does* write a file. A binary file with content, yet you claim the file is empty.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i edited my question accordingly

Comment: That's not yet complete: what is supposed to be the contents of `data2.txt`.

Comment: Close voters: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical_, no apparently this is not the case, the OP still has the problem even after applying hints from comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no `"rw+"` mode for [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/), you probably want the `"r+"` mode.
2. You need to check if `fopen` was successful.

Try this:

```
  ...
  fmain = fopen("data.txt", "r+");
  if (fmain == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can'topen file.\n"); exit(1);
  }
  fnew = fopen("i.txt", "r+");
  if (fnew == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can'topen file.\n"); exit(1);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for but  the answer but that was not the problem. I fixed it and it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check if the file you opened is not returning `NULL` and then only you can write to the file. As in here, the size of the data is fixed, write the entire array into a file is using the binary writing mode:

```
fp = fopen("data2.txt", "wb");
if(fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");   
      exit(1);             
   }    
fwrite(arr, sizeof(char), sizeof(arr), fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. however, the data2.txt is still empty after i run the program